# Set the diagonal values in SQL query with while loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a count variable like this:

```
declare @count as int = 1
```

I want to loop it for 3 rows and set the diagonal values in select statement

```
while (@count <= 3)
begin
    -- Set the diagonal value in select statement
end
```

The expected output would be

```
Select 1, Null, Null from table1 
Select Null,2,Null from table1
Select Null,Null,3 from table1
```

For simplicity I have taken 1 table -> table1, but I want similar output.

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Please elaborate on the background of this. It seems likely that SQL just isn't the right tool for the overall problem you try to solve.

Comment: What is a diagonal value?  And why do this in a loop instead of just setting the values on the appropriate records?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  "Diagonal" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Before asking another question I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You want to generate `select` statements that will output a row for _each_ row in `table1`, if any, but containing only constant values?

Answer (score 0):

The following code outputs the requested statements:

```
declare @Count as Int = 1;

while @Count <= 3
  begin
  print Concat( 'select ', case @Count when 1 then '1' else 'NULL' end, ', ',
    case @Count when 2 then '2' else 'NULL' end, ', ', case @Count when 3 then '3' else 'NULL' end,
    ' from table1;' );
  set @Count += 1;
  end;
```

A use-case doesn't leap to mind.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it,it gave me one idea and had implemented it. Thanks